# i'm getting this console log error after deployment react site. 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment

I'm getting this console log error after deployment react site.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'useRef')

The site is working perfectly in dev mode. when I build and host it will shows blank screen and above console log. [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Strict, it affects the app and check for bugs. It's Ideal to keep it, however for debugging you can look at stripping out the Strict mode. Secondly, check the API call and the correct header as your error above is mentioning about it. Lastly, check for your CORS configuration if you are making API calls to different origins.

It's not a direct solution as I can only guess from the error message.